# Move point on line defined by general form of equation

Tags: geometry

I have line defined by general form of equation: $$Ax + By + C = 0.$$

I know coordinates of point $P$ [$P_x$, $P_y$]. The point $P$ is on the line.

How can I find coordinates of points $P'$ and $P''$ in specific distance $d$ from the point $P$?

$|P'P| = d = |PP''|$

```
------------P'------P------P''------------------ <- line Ax + By + C = 0
            <------>|<------>
                d   |   d
```

Comment: you should solve a system of equations obtained by noticing that these two points are just the intersection of a given circle and a given straight line (notice that the equations are not linear)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\left(u,v\right)$ be the coördinates of $P$.

Then any point $P'$ on the line can be written as $\left(u,v\right)+\lambda\left(B,-A\right)$
for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

Here $\overline{PP'}=d$ means that
$\left\Vert \lambda\left(B,-A\right)\right\Vert =d$ or equivalently
$$|\lambda|=d\times\left\Vert \left(B,-A\right)\right\Vert ^{-1}=\frac{d}{\sqrt{A^{2}+B^{2}}}$$

This enables you to find the coördinates of $P'$.

Comment: Thank you :-). This is exactly what I needed.